# How to swap filenames in directory?

Tags: java

I am trying to do such task using that piece of code:

```
    File copyOfFirstVar= tmp1;
    File copyOfSecondVar= tmp2;

    File tmpVar = File.createTempFile("temp", "tempFile");

    tmp1.renameTo(tmpVar)
    tmp2.renameTo(copyOfFirstVar);
    tmp1.renameTo(copyOfSecondVar);
```

where tmp1 and tmp2 are objects from File class -> files I want to rename,
but that doesn't do anything.

Comment: What do you mean "it doesn't do anything" ? No error, no effect, nothing?

Comment: you need to save filename in copyoffirstvar(string variable) instead of whole object.

Comment: `File copyOfFirstVar= tmp1;` this actually just references the exact same file handle another time. If you rename `tmp1`you rename `copyOfFirstVar` as well. Thus `tmp2.renameTo(copyOfFirstVar);` will most probably return false since the file `tempFile` already exists.

Comment: Check the return value of `renameTo` in every step. If it returns `false, then the rename operation failed for some reason (and you can continue exploring further in that direction)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was said in the comments, you are referencing several times the same `File` (which is the `temp` file).

Since :

```
File copyOfFirstVar= tmp1;
File copyOfSecondVar= tmp2;
```

Your logic becomes :

```
tmp1.renameTo(tmpVar);  // now tmp1 and tmpVar are references to the same file
tmp2.renameTo(tmp1);    // now tmp2 and tmp1 are references to the same file
tmp1.renameTo(tmp2);    // see above
```

So you end up with `tmp1`, `tmp2` and `tmpVar` all three referencing the same `File` .

You should avoid using `File` references for your swapping, just use paths as `String`.

```
File copyOfFirstVar= tmp1;
File copyOfSecondVar= tmp2;

String firstPath = copyOfFirstVar.getAbsolutePath();
String secondPath = copyOfSecondVar.getAbsolutePath();

File tmpVar = File.createTempFile("temp", "tempFile");

tmp1.renameTo(tmpVar);
tmp2.renameTo(new File(firstPath));
tmp1.renameTo(new File(secondPath));
```

Also note as other persons pointed out, that `renameTo` will fail if the destination `File` exists.

Comment: In the last line of your code I have to do `tmpVar.renameTo(new File(secondPath));` If I do it with tmp1 then the file from tmp2 (in its new destination) is renamed to tmp2's origin. Is this strange behavior in my code or is there a mistake in yours?

Answer (score 0):

File.createTempFile(...) will create a physical file in the "temp" folder. So renaming another file to that name will fail as file already exist.

Comment: follow the example here to renaming files https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-rename-file-in-java/

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your program is you are changing/swaping even path along with the file name, so even after you perform renameTO it actually renaming the file once again with same old name.

Below is the program to achieve what you are trying to do:

```
public class SwapFileName {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file1 = new File("C:\\temp1\\asd.txt");
        File file2 = new File("C:\\temp2\\dsa.txt");
        boolean isSuccess = swapName(file1, file2);
        System.out.println(isSuccess);
    }
    public static boolean swapName(File tmp1, File tmp2) {
        String path1 = tmp1.getAbsolutePath().substring(0, tmp1.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(File.separator)+1);
        String fileName1 = tmp2.getName();
        File swapFile1 = new File(path1 + File.separator + fileName1);

        String path2 = tmp2.getAbsolutePath().substring(0, tmp2.getAbsolutePath().lastIndexOf(File.separator)+1);
        String fileName2 = tmp1.getName();
        File swapFile2 = new File(path2 + File.separator + fileName2);

        return (tmp1.renameTo(swapFile1) && tmp2.renameTo(swapFile2));

    }
}
```